# Custom 3D object and Image targets in Artoolkit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I have successfully tested the ARToolkit example given on [GitHub](https://github.com/artoolkit)
I tried to change the models in data but it still displays the two cars object. 
Can it have the custom 3D object and the image targets other than given in example?

Comment: What is the name of the example you are running? Which device are you running on?

When you change the model you have to rebuild the app and delete the previous app from the phone to make sure the cache is clean.

Comment: I am trying to export a model from [here](https://clara.io/view/4c1f3760-1cdf-4677-8ce3-c56e6025c968#)  I have rebuilt and deleted the previous version as well but no luck yet. I'm running on xiomi device.

Answer (score 0):

The models are loaded via Model1File variable.

```
const char *model1file = "Data/models/Ferrari_Modena_Spider.obj";
```

Have you changed this model?
Do you have a valid model to change it to?
Have you cleaned and rebuilt your code?

Comment: Yes, I did this and it's giving me log error. open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)